# Can you use a Managed Identity to access an Azure Function from an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have created an Azure Function that is called by a single Azure Web App I also created. I want to secure the Azure Function to only allow the Azure Web App to call it. I know how to do it by creating an App Registration and passing ClientID and Secrets. But I was wondering if I can do it by using the Azure Web App's Service Identity. That way I do not need to maintain the ClientID and Secrets.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. You will have to assign the permissions manually through PowerShell though: https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions.

Comment: Is the web app SPA or with backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can use MSI for this.

As an alternative approach you could also lock it down on the network layer by [integrating the App Service into a VNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) and [lock down incoming traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking-features#access-restriction-rules-based-on-service-endpoints) on the Function to that one subnet of the App Service.